# How to know which fragment the user is viewing?

Tags: android

I have created a TabLayout using ViewPager. I have four fragments.

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new AdminFragment(), "Admin Posts");
    adapter.addFragment(new MemberFragment(), "Member Posts");
    adapter.addFragment(new JoinFragment(), "Our Members");
    adapter.addFragment(new WebFragment(), "Our Website");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

How can I know which fragment the user is in from the parent activity.

```
public class AdminFragment extends Fragment{

    public AdminFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_admin, container, false);
    }

}
```

Comment: Override getItem() from your adapter and return fragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method will return name of fragment user currently viewing.

```
 public String returnCurrentFragmentName(){  

     int position = viewPager.getCurrentItem();

    switch (position) {
                case 0:
    //fragment is
                    return "AdminFragment";
                case 1:
    //fragment is
                   return "MemberFragment";
                case 2:
    //fragment is
                    return "JoinFragment";
                case 3:
    //fragment is
                    return "WebFragment";
                default:
                    return null;
    }
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `addOnPageChangeListener` to know when a page is changed and use `onPageSelected` to know which page is currently being selected by user.

If you need to know without page change on some specific event, you can use `viewPager.getCurrentItem()` to know which page is selected.

Answer (score 0):

In your parent activity do this

```
MyFragment myFragment = (MyFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Admin Posts");
if (myFragment != null && myFragment.isVisible()) {
// add your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use viewPager.getCurrentItem() to get the index of the current viewed item ... I hope this helps.